# Visualizing point attribute (int) with multiple dots / SVGs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, visualisation, svg

I am looking for a possibility to visualize an attribute in a point layer in QGIS, by displaying multiple dots or SVG graphics.

To be precise, I have a point layer about a disaster incident containing casualties for each town in a point layer. I would like to visualize this with dots or crosses for each town. For a town with 50 casualties I want to display 50 dots (or crosses) in e.g. 5 rows with 10 dots each.

Please refer to the attached image to get an idea. I do not desperately need that red dot, but I'm looking for displaying the integer attribute in amount of dots/crosses.

[image]

Comment: I think it's possible with a point displacement renderer, with a placement method : **Grid** but you have to superpose as many points as casualties : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#point-displacement-renderer

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Geometry Generator in your style layer

`collect_geometries(array_foreach(generate_series(0,"fatalities"-1,1),translate($geometry, 5*(@element%3), 5*floor(@element/3)) ))`

This will generate as many crosses than there are fatalities. Adjust the X & Y offset rules to match the desired column layout.

And set the SVG symbol to be crosses

An answer which uses the same underlying technique: [QGIS Symbology - Display more symbols for each point depending on attribute numeric value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449099/qgis-symbology-display-more-symbols-for-each-point-depending-on-attribute-nume/449103?noredirect=1#comment752512_449103)

Comment: Shouldn't the translate part rather be like `translate ($geometry, 5*(@element%3), 5*floor(@element/3))`, where 5 can be replaces by any number for the distance between points?

Comment: Correct, thanks. I edited the answer (was not able to check in Qgis before posting)

Answer (score 3):

Python is ideal for repeating text characters. Just multiply a certain text character, for example `'●'` with a number, and it will show the `'●'` character repeated based on the defined number.

Knowing that you can create a custom function in the field expression to repeat '●' based on the casualties field.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def repeat_txt(numfield, feature, parent):
    return '●' * numfield
```

In the Layer styling → labeling, go to expression → Custom → double-click to add `repeat_txt` function with casualties number field like this:

```
repeat_txt("casualties_number_field")
```

[image]

where `"Num"` is the field for the number of casualties.

The result is like this:

[image]

If you want the circles to be organized every 5 circles per line you need to update the expression as follows

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import re

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def repeat_txt(numfield, feature, parent):
    txt = '?' * numfield
    txt_wrap = re.sub("(.{5})", "\\1\n",txt , 0, re.DOTALL)
    return txt_wrap
```

The re function came from the brilliant answer on StackExchange [Insert a newline character every 64 characters using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657703/2889023)

Then reuse the same expression

```
repeat_txt("casualties_number_field")
```

The result is like this (the numbers are shown for your reference)

[image]

If you do not want the symbol, you can turn it off the symbology and select `No Symbols`

This is the final result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the solution by @ahmadhanb, you can set a label with the following expression for the input (`Value`). Labels are easier to handle than geometry generator and the expression is simpler.

Use the following expression and replace `your_field_name` to the name of the field containing the numbers and select an icon like the dagger character `†` ([UNICODE 2020, html 8224](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2020)), included already in the expression; you could also reproduce it with the expression `char(8224)`. Alternatively, use the latin cross `✝` ([Unicode 271D](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+271D)):

```
array_to_string (
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (1,"your_field_name"),
        '†'  ||  if (@element%3=0,'\n','')
    ),''
)
```

[image]