# Stack SVG points based on attribute table

Tags: qgis, point

I am a total beginner in QGIS.

For example, if a province has 20k something, I want a SVG marker to appear 20 times over that province.

Kind of like this, but with the images over the province.

[image]

Comment: The same question was asked a while ago, but I cant find it now.. Here is a similar one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449099/qgis-symbology-display-more-symbols-for-each-point-depending-on-attribute-nume

Comment: that seems to be the case, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it work